# Calculating pi using infinite series in C#

Tags: c#, double, decimal, division, pi

I tried to write the following program in C# to calculate pi using infinite recursion, but I keep getting confused about integer/double/decimal division.

I really have no clue why this isn't working, so pardon me for my lack of understanding of strongly typed stuff, as I'm still learning C#.

Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numeratornext = 2;
            int denominatornext = 5;

            decimal findto = 100.0M;
            decimal pi = 0.0M;
            decimal halfpi = 1.0M;
            int seriesnum = 1;
            int seriesden = 3;

            for (int i = 0; i < findto; i++)
            {
                halfpi += Decimal.Divide((decimal)seriesnum, (decimal)seriesden);
                //System.Console.WriteLine(Decimal.Divide((decimal)seriesnum, (decimal)seriesden).ToString());
                seriesnum *= numeratornext;
                seriesden *= denominatornext;
                numeratornext++;
                denominatornext += 2;
            }

            pi = halfpi * 2;

            System.Console.WriteLine(pi.ToString());
            System.Console.ReadLine();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are going to run into problems quickly unless the Decimal type is infinite precision because you will run out of digits.

Comment: "infinite recursion" will almost certainly need an infinite-size stack. I'm not aware, off the top of my head, of any architecture that supports this :-)

Comment: You might consider accessing this web-page in code to "harvest" pi up to a million digits worth. Or this article has C# code : http://www.omegacoder.com/?p=91

Comment: @Paxdiablo: actually no :) depending on the algorithm and the compiler you Can have infinite recursion with stack one Call deep at any time

Comment: why the answer is 19.113965328731964022456727092? instead of 3.14...is your program based on some prewritten algorithm. if please mention.

Comment: I find it funny that this question is now receiving answers a more than a year after it was posted. ;) Though I can't remember anything about what I was doing, I remember that it was for fun, and that I eventually wrote a form of this algorithm in some other language to get reasonable approximations. Thanks, anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion arises because you're using `int` and `decimal`, both of which are better suited for integers or fixed-precision financial calculations. My suggestion would be to simply declare *all* of your numeric variables as `double` here, which will remove any ambiguity about what the types of your return values are, since any mathematical operation on two doubles results in another double.

(Aside from this, your algorithm is wrong. However, the wrongness of your algorithm is a separate issue from the types you're using.)

Comment: Looking more than a year back, I'm afraid I can't really respond to this question as I don't remember what I was trying to do. Thanks for the help, anyways.

Comment: @Jonathan, woah. I didn't even realize this was such an old question. It showed up on the active page for some reason and I answered and never even looked at the date.